# MATLAB AppDesigner ListBox

Tags: matlab

Good afternoon!

I'm currently trying to build an app with MATLAB using App Designer. The goal is to be able to plot data using multiple GPX files, which I have successfully done. I'm curious as to how I should go about populating my Listbox.

Is there a way for Listbox to get populated with filenames depending on the folder you select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir` to list folder's content, convert names list to cell array, and populate the ListBox Items with the cell array.

Assume you have a Button with `ButtonButtonPushed` callback, and you wish to let the user select a folder, and then populate the list box with all *.gpx files.

You can do it as follows:

```
% Button button pushed function
function ButtonButtonPushed(app)
    selpath = uigetdir(); %Open dialog box for selecting folder.
    gpx_files = dir(fullfile(selpath, '*.gpx')); %Dir all *.gpx in selected folder.
    %Populate listbox with file names:
    app.ListBox.Items = {gpx_files(:).name};
end
```

The statement `app.ListBox.Items = {gpx_files(:).name};` populates the ListBox.

- `gpx_files(:).name` is a list of file names.
- `{gpx_files(:).name}` creates a cell array out of the list.
- `app.ListBox.Items = {gpx_files(:).name};` Sets the `Items` property of the ListBox with the created cell array.

---

**Getting the full path of the selected file:**

1. Keep the selected folder:
   Add a private property named `selpath` (use the red P+ in the designer [code view] to add new property, and edit the name of the property):

   ```
   properties (Access = private)
       selpath % Store selected path
   end
   ```
2. Store the selected path in `selpath` property when button is pressed:

   ```
   % Button pushed function: Button
   function ButtonButtonPushed(app, event)
       app.selpath = uigetdir(); %Open dialog box for selecting folder.
       gpx_files = dir(fullfile(app.selpath, '*.gpx')); %Dir all *.gpx in selected folder.

       %Populate listbox with file names:
       app.ListBox.Items = {gpx_files(:).name};
   end
   ```

   Now selected path is stored in `app.selpath`.
3. Add "ListBoxChangeValue" Callback (right click the list box in design view).
4. Edit the code of ListBoxValueChanged function:
   The `value` returned `value = app.ListBox.Value;` is the name of the selected file 
   (you don't need to use `strcmpi`).
   Use `fullfile` function to concatenate the path with the file name.

   ```
   % Value changed function: ListBox
   function ListBoxValueChanged(app, event)
       value = app.ListBox.Value;
       selected_file = fullfile(app.selpath, value); %Get the full path of selected file.
       disp(selected_file) %Change the code to load selected_file
   end
   ```

   The above code displays `selected_file` string in the Command Window.
   Replace the `disp(selected_file)` with you own code (loading and plotting the gpx file).

---

Here is the complete code of App1 (most of the code was generated automatically):

```
classdef App1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure      matlab.ui.Figure
        Button        matlab.ui.control.Button
        LabelListBox  matlab.ui.control.Label
        ListBox       matlab.ui.control.ListBox
    end


    properties (Access = private)
        selpath % Store selected path
    end


    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)

        end

        % Button pushed function: Button
        function ButtonButtonPushed(app, event)
            app.selpath = uigetdir(); %Open dialog box for selecting folder.
            gpx_files = dir(fullfile(app.selpath, '*.gpx')); %Dir all *.gpx in selected folder.

            %Populate listbox with file names:
            app.ListBox.Items = {gpx_files(:).name};
        end

        % Value changed function: ListBox
        function ListBoxValueChanged(app, event)
            value = app.ListBox.Value;
            selected_file = fullfile(app.selpath, value); %Get the full path of selected file.
            disp(selected_file) %Change the code to load selected_file
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [101 101 640 480];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Create Button
            app.Button = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.Button.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ButtonButtonPushed, true);
            app.Button.Position = [43 380 114 49];
            app.Button.Text = 'Select Folder';

            % Create LabelListBox
            app.LabelListBox = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.LabelListBox.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.LabelListBox.VerticalAlignment = 'top';
            app.LabelListBox.Position = [300 412 44 15];
            app.LabelListBox.Text = 'List Box';

            % Create ListBox
            app.ListBox = uilistbox(app.UIFigure);
            app.ListBox.ValueChangedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @ListBoxValueChanged, true);
            app.ListBox.Position = [359 355 100 74];

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = App1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Another question I have for this application is how to display this data on a plot, dependent on my selection. My current code allows me to plot every single GPX file over a worldmap from AppDesigner. Again, I'd like to be able to select from the list of files being populated in the listbox. It would be amazing if I could multi-select and plot the data. Would strcmpi be applicable in this situation where I would compare the item name in listbox with the filename from the folder? If so, how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: I edited the post. multi-select is not supported by the List Box control.  In case all you need to do is selecting a file, you can use [uigetfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) (List Box is not needed).  `uigetfile` supports multiple selection (read the documentation of `uigetfile`).

Comment: Correction: List Box **multi-select** is supported. You can enable multi-select by adding `app.ListBox.Multiselect = 'on';` to the code of `startupFcn(app)` function. But then you need to add another button so the user can mark that selection was finished.  `app.ListBox.Value` is going to return a cell array. It's going to make my post too long...

Comment: Ah okay, so for the sake of what I'd like to achieve, the multi-select option isn't going to be helpful. I imagined I could have used multiple selection to tell my app to plot multiple tracking data onto a single map. What would you recommend then?

Comment: I don't know enough about the user interface of your program to give you a recommendation. I am also not the right person to ask, since user interfaces and  mapping are not my expertise.